# gf with search pattern instead of line number

Tags: find, file

```
vim file +80
```

will open `file` in vim, with cursor at line 80

```
vim file +/if/
```

will open `file` in vim, with cursor at first line containing `if`.

For `vim file +80`, inside vim, there is `gF`.

**The question:**

Inside vim is there any equivalent of `vim file +/if/`?

which open `<cfile>` and go to first line that match a pattern.

Comment: `gF` exists because some programs may produce output of the form `file:line` and such. But `file:/pattern/` doesn't seem to occur often. And if you really need it, you can create a mapping of your own.

Comment: Thx, I will try to implement it with custom mapping. Should I close or delete the question, or just leave it alone?

Comment: If you're going to implement such functionality and feel it can be of some use and/or interest for others, you can give a self-answer.

Comment: Ctags has output with patterns like this